# no node available elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search

I'm using elasticsearch in my project. but when deploying the project on a server it gives the exception, I read other same questions but didn't find solution:
I changed the port to 9300 and it wasn't solved.

```
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{EEv7PPi1SYqxodHCtCrfEw}{192.168.0.253}{192.168.0.253:9200}]]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:344)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:242)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:59)
```

This is my configuration for elasticsearch in my code:

```
 public static void postConstruct() {
            try {
                Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                        .put("cluster.name","my-application").build();
                client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(Bundle.application.getString("ELASTIC_ADDRESS")), Integer.parseInt(Bundle.application.getString("9200"))));
                try {
                    client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("tempdata").get();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The version of elasticsearch bot in my project and on the server is the same. and this is what i get when I curl 'http://x.x.x.x:9200/?pretty'

```
{
  "name" : "node-1",
  "cluster_name" : "my-application",
  "cluster_uuid" : "_na_",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.2.2",
    "build_hash" : "f9d9b74",
    "build_date" : "2017-02-24T17:26:45.835Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

when I change the port to 9300, after some seconds the exception I see is this:

```
MasterNotDiscoveredException[null]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:211)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:307)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:237)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterService.java:1157)
```

This is log of elasticsearch and I have no idea what are host1 and host2:

```
   [2018-07-16T15:40:59,476][DEBUG][o.e.a.a.i.g.TransportGetIndexAction] [gCJIhnQ] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2018-07-16T15:41:29,478][DEBUG][o.e.a.a.i.g.TransportGetIndexAction] [gCJIhnQ] timed out while retrying [indices:admin/get] after failure (timeout [30s])
[2018-07-16T15:41:29,481][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] path: /bad-request, params: {index=bad-request}
org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: null
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:211) [elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:307) [elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:237) [elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterService.java:1157) [elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:527) [elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_91]
```

Comment: Did you try the 9300 port number?

Comment: yes but nothing changed

Comment: Set the network host to 0.0.0.0 in elasticsearch.yml config  and try again.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: add the line network.host: 0.0.0.0 in your elasticsearch.yml config.(in linux its location is /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml)

Comment: no change. isn't need to restart elasticsearch after changing elasticsearch.yml file?

Comment: Yes, you need to restart it. In case of no change please post the elasticsearch logs for more details.

Comment: I edited the question and added the log of elasticsearch to it

Comment: What is the host1 and host2? These names can't be resolved and you got UnknownHostException.

Comment: I found host1 and host2 and changed them to defualt discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
now the log of elastic search is what I put in my question @Mushtu

Answer (score 2):

Because the number of comments has increased, here are some tips that might be helpful. I assume that you are using a standalone elasticsearch instance started using ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch as the master node on the server machine.

1. Make sure the elasticsearch on the server configured as a master node. Refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/modules-node.html for more details about nodes in elasticsearch.
2. Make sure the elasticsearch on the server is bounded to a non-loopback address. For details about this refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/network.host.html
3. Check the transport client version be compatible with the server version.
4. Increase the mmap counts as they said [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html). In Linux by running the command: sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
5. Check the transport port number on the server and it is reachable from outside. Defaults to 9300-9400
6. Check the elasticsearch service logs on the server to be sure it is configured as you did!